# How to delete margin which created by cufon?

Tags: html, css, margin, cufon, rule

Watsup guys! I use cufon for creating unusual fonts. I have `<h2>` tag:
`<h2> Our consulting</h2>` after cufon actions it add css margin rule, and i cant redefine it. Who knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: in FF, use FireBug, inspect the element, get id or class name and target it in CSS

Answer (score 1):

i think u must recreate the CUFON script and take care for margin while creating.

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Answer (score 0):

Adding overflow:hidden !important; to the container or  worked for me. Hope it helps!